# Import image with migrate tools changing its name

Tags: 8, migrations

I’m trying to migrate some data from a remote rest/api (json) using the plugin source url. My problem is in the json i consume the image name field comes with an incorrect value.

In `imageName` comes '0_3.jpg' and the correct name is '0_3.png', for example

So i have the following code trying to transform the name:

```
  source_full_path:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/source_base_path
        - imageName:
            plugin: str_replace
            source: imageName
            search: "jpg"
            replace: "png"
```

but this gives the following error:

> TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray::getValue() must be of the type array, null given

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

```
_image_fixed:
  - plugin: str_replace
    source: imageName
    search: "jpg"
    replace: "png"

source_full_path:
  - plugin: concat
    delimiter: /
    source:
      - constants/source_base_path
      - @_image_fixed
```

Or:

```
source_full_path:
  - plugin: concat
    delimiter: /
    source:
      - constants/source_base_path
      - imageName
  - plugin: str_replace
    search: "jpg"
    replace: "png"
```

Comment: your solutions work perfectly. thanks!